# Liquibase loadUpdateData is doing only Insert in derby

Tags: java, derby, liquibase

I have new values i want into my database and i saw by this documentation http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/load_update_data.html
that there is a possible soluation already however once i created the changelog only an insert is beeing executed and not an update on duplicate key.

My Database is DERBY 10.12.1.1 and Liquibase 3.5.1

This is my changeset

```
 <changeSet author="mva" id="changes">
  <loadUpdateData encoding="UTF-8"
                tableName="vi_prop_def"
                primaryKey="pk_prop_def"
                file="vi_prop_def-type.csv">
  <column name="guid" type="STRING"/>
  <column name="name" type="STRING"/>
  <column name="description" type="STRING"/>
  <column name="value_type" type="STRING"/>
  <column name="property_order" type="NUMERIC"/>
  <column name="group_guid" type="STRING"/>
  <column name="required" type="NUMERIC"/>
  <column name="is_collection" type="NUMERIC"/>
</loadUpdateData>
```

And this is the executed statement

```
Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'PK_PROP_DEF' defined on 'VI_PROP_DEF'. [Failed SQL: INSERT INTO APP.vi_prop_def (guid, name, description, value_type, property_order, group_guid, required, is_collection) VALUES ('b7ede117-4925-4e44-83ac-dfb10e8fc0f8', 'productionBeginDate', 'my production Date', 'DATE', 38, 'f2262f52-0cd9-4d69-ac19-dce871aa4a1e', 1, 0)]
```

there is indeed a value already inserted but i was expecteding that liquibase generates an insert followed by a derby specific update on dublicate key.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be accurately  following the instructions on this page: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/load_update_data.html, but with one exception: you have varchar(255) instead of string listed as the type. I seem to recall they have some inconsistencies in their docs so you may be correct and their docs incorrect.

Additionally, is it possible that you have duplicate data in the import file? If changing the type doesn't work I would suggest using a simpler example for a fake table, like "users" which has only an id and a name column to verify it works as expected when appending a new user to that fake list.

One last thing that struck me as odd was that you had a guid column that was not your pk. Why is your guid not the PK? Perhaps you have a guid and also a unique key constraint but it seems strange the way it is. Verify your schema matches your assumptions just in case.

Comment: guid is my parent key, however i am using the primary key constraint which seems to work because by duplication i have what i actually wanted but i need the update statement, the insert one is ABSOLUTELY correct

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the InserOrUpdateGenerator (3.5.1) and apparently there is NO implementation for Derby and many other DBMS so i guess i have to take the long route -> delete ->insert. Unfortunately they dont keep their documentation accurate :(